# How do I parse a response using a global variable in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I modified my *start_requets* method to be:

```
def start_requests(self):
    array = list(open("file", 'r'))
    for i in array:
        yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://example.org/test.php?id=" + i)
```

How can I access the value of i in the *parse* method?

I tried setting a global variable *idd* and adding

```
global idd
idd = i
```

in the *start_requests* method and then

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = DataItem()
    item['id'] = idd
```

But all of items' id fields were   filled with idd's last value.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is your parse method?

Comment: I only posted a part of it, the rest seemed irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (and probably the easiest) option would be to pass it inside [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta):

```
yield scrapy.Request("http://example.org/test.php?id=" + i, 
                     meta={"index": i},
                     dont_filter=True)
```

Then, read it in `parse()`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    index = response.meta["index"]
```

Comment: can we use this in adding to list all the response with respect to URL